# Ошибка при сохранении диаграммы бд

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Создал бд, таблицы. Построил диаграмму, не дает сохранить. Пересоздавать не хочу лишний раз. Помогите великие хранители SQL
ssms 18, express 19
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая у вас версия SSMS? Во многих старых версиях SSMS было много ошибок с диаграммами.

Comment: ssms 18, а express 19

Comment: Именно по этой причине. Попробуйте SSMS 18.10

Comment: Какая у вас версия SSMS? Во многих старых версиях SSMS было много ошибок с диаграммами.
Именно по этой причине не дает сохранить. Попробуйте SSMS 18.10 [![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23vw8.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23vw8.jpg)

Comment: сходите в Tools -> Options -> Designers и снимите галку с Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation

Comment: вам собственно об этом  и написано в тексте ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вашу проблему можно найти просто прочитав сообщение об ошибке. Предлагается проследовать в настройки по пути `Tools -> Options -> Designers` и выставить галку "Prevent saving changes thath require table re-creation" или в вашем случае *"запретить сохранение изменений требующих повторного создания таблицы"*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо за ответ